# Pandas generate a column of random numbers based on ID column

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to generate random numbers from 1 to n based on the ID column in my DataFrame. Repeating values in this ID column should have the same random number. A Random number should be assigned to more than 1 ID, but the number of IDs belonging to each random number should be equal or the most equal as possible. I'd also like a seed value that way I can replicate the results.

A very simple example is let's say I have an ID column with values of A,B,C,D,E. I'd like to assign a random number of 1 to 2. So in this example, IDs A,B,E would be assigned to random number 1 and IDs C,D to 2.

```
ID   Random
A    1
C    2
A    1
B    1
E    1
D    2
```

Also, I have a very large DataFrame so speed is very important.

Update: What I tried previously was getting a unique list of the IDs then generating random numbers for each, but I made a DataFrame and tried to merge the 2 DataFrames which was too time consuming.

Comment: Can you please update the question to show what you’ve tried / researched so far?  Off the bat I’d say crate a dict with `{id: num}` pairs and map them to the column.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to S3DEV he suggested mapping a dictionary to the column which was a lot faster.

```
ID_list = df['ID'].unique()
random_list = np.random.randint(1, 2, size=len(ID_list))
dic = {ID_list[i]: random_list[i] for i in range(len(ID_list))} 
df['Random'] = df['ID'].map(dic)
```

Comment: No worries mate, glad it helped. (Feel free to upvote any of my other answers).  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

To fix your approach (i.e. create side dataframe):

```py
n = 10

ids = df[["ID"]].drop_duplicates()
ids["Random"] = np.random.randint(1, n, len(ids))
ids.set_index("ID", inplace=True)
df.set_index("ID", inplace=True)
df["Random"] = ids["Random"]
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Outputs:

```py
  ID  Random
0  A       6
1  C       7
2  A       6
3  B       4
4  E       1
5  D       6
```